# Dynamically and flexibly generate auto-number on a different column than the result of a formula without a helper column or script

Tags: google-sheets

I have an existing formula that merges every other column of the range specified in the cell B4, filters out empty cells, sorts it alphabetically and removes duplicates. The formula is in A6. Here's the formula:

`=LET(x,SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(INDIRECT($B$4), SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COLUMNS(INDIRECT($B$4))/2, 0), 1, 1, 2))))),FILTER(x,x<>""))`

Note: This formula throws an error in Microsoft 365 but I wish it can work though unnecessary.

Can someone please tell me how to auto-generate numbering on a different column within that same formula where the starting number can be adjusted (for example, the counting starts at 3 > 3,4,5), the increment can be adjusted (for example, instead of 1,2,3 the increment is 2 > 1,3,5), and the position of the auto-numbering column can be adjusted (for example, auto-populated column is two columns before the result column or 10 columns after the result column.)

Tried the following:

1. `=SEQUENCE(ROWS([my formula]), 1, 1, 1)` or `=SEQUENCE(COUNTA([my formula]))` but was on a different column which is not what is needed and both only generated the numbering without anything else
2. `=BYROW([my formula],LAMBDA(row,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(row)),row+1,"")))` and got "Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But 'value' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

I would imagine a combination of sequence, byrow, choosecol and/or makearray but I couldn't figure out how to while ensuring that it is flexible enough to be reused in different scenarios for future use.

Please help.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample spreadsheet with dummy values, and also your current output and expected output so that we can further help with your question?

Comment: @Serenity Sure! Here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IjUVnDCeG8-7WtZ_Cq9DbfJnzeqe5IpnNQv03MlHxBI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you showcase the ideal expected output (**by entering it manually**) in a separate tab perhaps?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow Apologies! I was trying to add more examples to showcase what I mean by the "flexibility" of the formula. Already added the tab with the manual expected out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Modifying your existing formula for `example_2` scenario; you can just remove the blank columns used within hstack `,,,` to achieve `example_1` scenario:*

```js
=LET(x,SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(INDIRECT($E$4), SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COLUMNS(INDIRECT($E$4))/2, 0), 1, 1, 2))))),
     Σ,FILTER(x,x<>""),
     ifna(hstack(sequence(rows(Σ)),,,,Σ)))
```

[image]

Comment: What sorcery is Σ! That's exactly how I wanted it to look like - compact and flexible. I figured out how to adjust the starting number, adjust the increments (steps), and adjust the number of columns in between the two columns. The only thing that's missing is to be able to switch the columns so that the masterlist will be on the left and the numbering will be somewhere to its right (example #3).

Comment: *Σ* is just an identifier I used for *let function*; you can replace it with something of your convenience. for example_3 this part will change to `hstack(Σ,,,,sequence(rows(Σ)))`

Comment: I couldn't have figured it out without you. Thank you so much and happy holidays!